# Is there a chance that a DC/DC controller was damaged when a bad feedback network caused its output to exceed its absolute max limit?

Tags: feedback, switching-regulator, damage

I'm currently debugging an issue with a DC/DC controller. The part is a LTC3833. It turns out that the engineer who was working on this accidentally pointed to incorrect part numbers for the passive components, which led to the FB resistor network to be wrong. The FB resistor network that was initially installed led to an output voltage that was over the controllers output max absolute limit. Upon discovering that, we adjusted the FB resistor network to match what we want. However, we noticed we were still getting an incorrect output voltage (3.0V) and that the FB voltage was 0.3V. We doubled the check the other passive components and verified they were okay. Is there a chance that the chip got damaged when we first turned it on with the incorrect resistor values for the output voltage?

Comment: If you exceed "absolute maximum" ratings even for an instant, it is safe to assume that the part is irreparably damaged.

Comment: the chance exists that the chip becomes damaged even if the resistors are correct

Comment: VOUT, SENSE+, SENSE– Voltages.................. –0.6V to 6V. Means absolute max

Comment: I've blown several LTC SMPS chips trying to add new potentiometers, they are not very robust at all. They go over-voltage output and fry themselves instantly. I stick with XL now, and haven't had the same issue, must have additional stupid user protections compared to LTC...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course it is possible that it is damaged.

If the output voltage was set too high to the downstream components, they are now damaged and might draw excess current and clamp the voltage.

The controller itself can be damaged too.

Comment: It looks like the part was indeed damaged due to the incorrect passive components. We've replaced that part and the system now works. It's unfortunate that that little mistake did this.

Comment: "It's unfortunate that that little mistake did this". In development I typically populate and test all the power supplies first, or at least temporarily sever them from the rest of the circuit. It helps limit the rework required. A colleague managed to specify a 5V variant of a regulator instead of a 3V3 on one board...ten very expensive sensors ruined in an instant!